# Python groupby month and weekday

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having issue in the below groupby problem.

Step 1: Example of original df:

| SITE_ID | MONTH | WEEKDAY | U_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.115 |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.116 |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.117 |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.5 |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.6 |
| IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.7 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.09 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.10 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 2 | 0.11 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.07 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.08 |
| IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 1 | 3 | 0.09 |

The output of below command is shown in the picture:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','SITE_ID'])['U_RATE'].mean()
```

[image]

The text version of this table is like below:

| Index | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 0.11688 |
| 1/2/IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 0.06086 |
| 1/3/IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00 | 0.10390 |
| 1/3/IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00 | 0.08696 |

Step2:
For next step, I was trying to get month1/weekday2 (red frame) mean and standard deviation of rates among sites by

```
df1.groupby('MONTH','WEEKDAY').agg(['mean','std']).rename({'mean':'avg'},axis=1)
```

I got the error:
**ValueError: No axis named WEEKDAY for object type Series**

Any ideas on how to group by month and weekday? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please include a sample of your `df1` as text not an image? The output of `df1.head(5).to_dict()` should work. It just makes it easier to copy and test, and will help us more efficiently help you.

Comment: Actually, a sample of `df` as well would be helpful, since your second groupby depends on values that are in `df` but no longer in `df1` from your assignment in the first step.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: You cannot get second dataframe with just `df1 = df.groupby(['MONTH','WEEKDAY','SITE_ID'])['U_RATE'].mean()` you must be doing something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `reset_index` after you take the `mean` you will take your DataFrame from a multi-index to a single index.

After that's done, you can groupby as like you did the first time.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SITE_ID': {0: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00', 1: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00',
                               2: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00', 3: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00',
                               4: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00', 5: 'IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00',
                               6: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00', 7: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00',
                               8: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00', 9: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00',
                               10: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00', 11: 'IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00'},
                   'MONTH': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1,
                             5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1,
                             10: 1, 11: 1},
                   'WEEKDAY': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3,
                               5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2,
                               9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 3},
                   'U_RATE': {0: 0.115, 1: 0.116, 2: 0.117,
                              3: 0.5, 4: 0.6, 5: 0.7, 6: 0.09,
                              7: 0.1, 8: 0.11, 9: 0.07,
                              10: 0.08, 11: 0.09}})

df1 = df.groupby(['MONTH', 'WEEKDAY', 'SITE_ID'])['U_RATE'].mean().reset_index()

df2 = df1 \
    .groupby(['MONTH', 'WEEKDAY']) \
    .agg(['mean', 'std'])['U_RATE'] \
    .reset_index() \
    .rename({'mean': 'avg'}, axis=1)

# For Display
print(df1.to_string(index=False))
print()
print(df2.to_string(index=False))
```

DF1:

```
MONTH  WEEKDAY                   SITE_ID  U_RATE
    1        2 IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00   0.116
    1        2 IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00   0.100
    1        3 IA00080IS0020800ERA208E00   0.600
    1        3 IA00080IS0023700ERA237E00   0.080
```

DF2:

```
MONTH  WEEKDAY   avg      std
    1        2 0.108 0.011314
    1        3 0.340 0.367696
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that what you saved under *df1* is **not** any *DataFrame*.
It is a *Series*.

I think, you can run your formula on *df* (instead of *df1*):

```
result = df.groupby(['MONTH', 'WEEKDAY']).U_RATE.agg(['mean','std'])\
    .rename({'mean':'avg'},axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
                 avg       std
MONTH WEEKDAY                 
1     2        0.108  0.010826
      3        0.340  0.291822
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The std_dev seems different from manually calculated. I'll take a deeper look and thanks for the idea!

Comment: It depends whether you want to compute avg and mean of original data (for each group) or of means (for each *MONTH*, *WEEKDAY* and *SITE_ID*).